# gvim -- problem when imap'ing certain unicode characters

Tags: vim, unicode

I have a few vim shortcuts to insert Greek and math characters. (for nicer looking comments and Haskell code.) Unfortunately, the "forall" character seems to insert `∀þX` instead of just `∀`. Does this behavior happen for you, and is there a workaround?

```
imap <expr> <A-a> "α"
imap <expr> <A-b> "β"
imap <expr> <A-g> "γ"
imap <expr> <A-l> "λ"
imap <expr> <S-A-f> "∀"
imap <expr> <S-A-e> "∃"
```

You'll have to use `gvim` in order to use the "Alt" key combinations; you can change the "A" to a "C" and try to use it in `vim` if desirable. The same error comes up for me.

(It also seems that I can't map both "alt+key" and "shift+alt+key", but I'll worry about that when it becomes a problem.)

Comment: Check if alt-F won't insert something already. In my case, it inserts a 'ƒ', so it's jut a matter of mapping ƒ to ∀. By the way, shift+alt+f is just alt+F. And also, I'm curious: why <expr> and then a string? does it have any advantages over `imap <a-x> ∀`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like one of the bugs related to «0x80 byte starts an escape sequence» problem: in UTF-8 `∀` is `\xe2\x88\x80`... you see the last byte, do you? If you want to use it you should change mapping to

```
inoremap <expr> <S-A-f> "\u2200"
```

Also note the `nore`: don't use `*map` unless you know why you prefer it to `nore` version, it may save you from troubles when your vimrc grows. Another option is

```
inoremap <S-A-f> ∀
```